# Association in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

I have three models `User`, `Supplier`, `Company`. There is **One to Many** relationship between `User` and `Supplier` and, `Company` and `Supplier` (a user has many supplier but a supplier belongs to one user). What would be right way to create such association in Rails 3? Also a `User has_many Courses through UserCourses`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got you correctly, it should be something like this:

User:

```
has_many :suppliers
has_many :user_courses
has_many :users, through: :user_courses
```

Supplier:

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :company
```

Company:

```
has_many :suppliers
```

Answer (score 1):

If Courses is another model along with User,Company and Supplier, then following should work.

User:
has_many :suppliers
has_many :user_courses
has_many :courses, :through => :user_courses

Supplier:
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :company

Company:
has_many :suppliers

Courses:
has_many :user_courses
has_many :users, :through => :user_courses